# How to handle TypeError in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an error that pops up like this:

```
dropdownMenu = OptionMenu(main, allvars, options)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

this pops up becasue there is no values in the dropdownMenu, to fix that I want to do the followng:

If this is my error, but the app is still running, Id like to implement a message box and destroy the app if that specific error pops up.

How can I do that? I have done some research and came back with try and expect statements.

This is what I have tried:

```
try:
 # some code
except TypeError:
 #add code here if this error pops up.
```

but that does nothing, even `Print("TypeError")` pops up on CMD

Comment: That error can only happen because of a bug in your code; you need to provide something in the `value` position. It isn't something that can happen randomly at runtime.

Comment: if I have no value? Sorry, that was my point, that I need to do something if there is no value

Comment: Then put `None` there. If the OptionMenu expects four arguments, you need to pass four arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says you don't have a value inside your `dropdownMenu`, like you mentioned in your question.

You haven't showed any code for us to look at properly, but I suggest you try place relevant code linked to the `dropdownMenu` inside `try:`.

Next, you mentioned about messagebox and destroying the app. For the implementing message box and destroy the app if that error shows up:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

try:
 #relevant code
except TypeError:
 messagebox.showinfo
 root.destroy()
```

Not quite sure, about that `root.destroy()` but that's a start!

Comment: I've put all the code in: this shows up: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: @flakedBros select all code inside `try:` and `except TypeError` and press the tab button. But do not highlight the `try:` & `except`

Comment: perfect! but the root.destroy is not working, ill look into it